# Jessie: cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain

Tags: raspbian, wifi, raspbian-jessie

I have this message repeated multiple times on Jessie.

```
cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
...
cfg80211: Exceeded CRDA call max attempts. Not calling CRDA
```

Everything looks like is working fine, however I'm not totally sure.

Any advise how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the CRDA package was missing from **Jessie**.
To fix this issue just install the CRDA package

```
apt-get install crda iw wireless-regdb
```

then `reboot` and the message will change as follows:

```
[   18.055887] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   18.075302] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[   18.151509] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[   18.161460] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
[   18.165822] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   18.183540] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[   18.195667] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
[   18.209284] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
[   18.222889] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[   18.234918] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
```

Answer (score 0):

This partially worked for me. The CRDA still wasn't set on reboot:

`[    7.968805] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    8.259604] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    8.267114] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    8.271820] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    8.286116] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.296448] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.306754] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.317328] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.329702] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    8.342143] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    8.352515] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    8.362778] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)`
.

Adding:

```
country=CA
```

to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf didn't work.

Adding:

```
REGDOMAIN=CA
```

to /etc/defaults/crda didn't work.
Then I read to also add:

```
COUNTRY=CA
```

to /etc/environment and that also didn't work.

Only way I could do it was to manually enter:

```
sudo iw reg set CA
```

After reboot. I made persistent by adding this to /etc/rc.local but I still get an unset region on boot and then it gets set when rc.local runs.
To me this seems an absolute mess and needs fixing!